# cakephp .htaccess, mime-types

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I have a cakephp 1.2 app (1.2.2.8120) and I am trying to change the mime-type for Japanese cell phones on certain pages with this one line of code in the app/webroot/.htaccess file:

AddType application/xhtml+xml .xhtml

This works for .xhtml files uploaded directly to the webroot folder, but regular cakephp pages don't work.

I have tried to add the same .htaccess line of code to the app/.htaccess and /.htaccess files but it did not work.
I also added the line:

header('Content-type: xhtml+xml');

to the beforeFilter() method of the app_controller, but that also did not work.

Thanks ahead of time for any help you can provide.

Comment: also, is AddType application/xhtml+xml .xhtml in .htaccess equivalent to header('Content-type: xhtml+xml'); in php?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just ended up using 
header("Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml; charset=shift-jis");

in the beforeRender method in app_controller. I will keep in mind your suggestion about the Request Handler in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there's no file involved with an `.xhtml` extension in a normal Cake app, so Apache can't identify the type. What's actually invoked is the `webroot/index.php` file, so you may want to set the type for `.php` files. I think I've seen this fail before though.

You could also try using `DefaultType application/xhtml+xml`.

<strike>Setting a PHP `header()` first thing in the `default.ctp` layout might be the best option though.</strike>
Using the RequestHandler Components [`respondAs()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/353/Responding-To-Requests) to set the header should be the best option. AFAIA that's equivalent to an Apache header.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.pagebakers.nl/2007/06/05/using-json-in-cakephp-12/

It looks like Cake abstracts content-type headers. You just need to switch the JSON content-type for the XHTML one.